# How to more easily specify tasks for batch, using command prefix tool?

Tags: bash, zsh, at

The tool `batch` that comes with the `atd` daemon is pretty useful in principle, running commands only when the system utilisation falls below a certain level (by default, 1.5). However, using it (and also `at`) is pretty ugly by modern standards: you either have to feed a script which can be run by `/bin/sh`, or type commands interactively into a basic prompt with no completion, color-coding, etc.

What would be really nice is a command prefix tool, more like `nice`, that one can put in front of any command to add it to the batch queue (and a similar utility for `at` would be handy, although that's not the main point of my question). For example, it might work like this:

`my-batchifying-command python some_longrunning_computational_script.py`

Does such a thing exist? If not, how might it be created? I use `zsh` for my main shell, but a `bash` answer would be equally OK and might have wider applicability.

Answer (score 1):

With `zsh` for simple commands:

```
my-batch() {print -r -- ${(qq)@} | batch}

my-batch python some_longrunning_computational_script.sh
```

would do it.

If you need more complex things like loops or redirections, you could do:

```
my-batch eval 'for i in ...; done'

my-batch eval 'echo test > /some/file'
```

But remember to use `sh`, not `zsh` syntax.

If you want to be able to avoid the `eval`, you could use this trick:

```
alias my-batch=':||'
preexec()
  if [[ $1 = my-batch\ * ]]; then
    print -r -- "${1#my-batch }" | batch
  fi
```

Again, be sure to use `sh` syntax.

Beware that it can be only **one** command (actually one pipeline). If you need more than one, use braces:

```
my-batch { ls > /tmp/a; date > /tmp/b; }
```

The idea above is that the `my-batch` command does nothing, does not even evaluate the arguments of the command because for instance `my-batch echo $(date)` expands to `:|| echo $(date)`, and it's `preexec` which is run each time a command line is accepted that does the job instead.

For `preexec`, `$1` is the full command line untouched. We just check if it starts with `"my-batch "`, strip that and send the rest to `batch`.

That explains why `my-batch` has to be at the beginning of the line. `cmd && my-batch ...` won't work for instance, and you can't do things like `my-batch foo || bar`, because it's actually going to be interpreted as `:|| foo || bar`.